# Java TreeSet Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I have a Vehicle class with fields: baseVehicleId, subModelId, notes and  partNo

If is the same baseVehicleId, subModelId and partNo , i want the object with the longest notes to remain( and delete the others)

I have this:

```
Comparator<Vehicle> comparator = new Comparator<Vehicle>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Vehicle a, Vehicle b) { 
                if(a.baseVehicleId().equals(b.baseVehicleId()) && String.valueOf(a.subModelId ()).equals(String.valueOf(b.subModelId ()))
                        && String.valueOf(a.partNo ()).equals(String.valueOf(b.partNo ())) 
                ))
                    return a.getOurnotes().compareTo(b.getOurnotes());
                // not good I know
                 return 1;
            }
        };

        TreeSet<Vehicle> treeSet = new TreeSet<Vehicle>(comparator);
```

How can i modify this code :/?
So for example if i have all the fields equal and the length of notes are greater then delete the other objects.

Comment: There is a solution but it would require Guava...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the method

```
maximum = Collections.max(collection, comparator);
```

for searching the maximum of the elements and then just delete the others with

```
collection.remove();
```

Inside the comparator you can't delete from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator's job is simply to say which of two objects comes first - there's no mechanism to manipulate the underlying collection during it's comparisons. I think you would want to think about this in a slightly different way: perform your filtering logic prior to adding an object to your collection.

I'd recommend just using a standard list, say `ArrayList` for sake of simplicity. Also you'd need to override the `equals()` method in your Vehicle class which returns `true` if two Vehicles share the same IDs and part numbers.

When it comes to adding new vehicles you can do something like this:

```
int vehicleIndex = myvehicles.indexOf(vehicle) // -1 if missing, otherwise 0 or greater to represent the index position

if (vehicleIndex == -1) {
    // No item in the list shares the ids/model/part numbers so can add
    myvehicles.add(vehicle)
} else {
    // There's another similar vehicle, better compare their notes:
    Vehicle existingVehicle = myvehicles.get(vehicleIndex); // retrieve the object from list so that we can compare it

    // check if the new vehicle has longer notes
    if (vehicle.getOurNotes().length > existingVehicle.getOurNotes().length) {
        // if it does, remove the old one from the list
        myvehicles.remove(vehicleIndex);
        // and add the new one. Effectively we've done a replacement
        myvehicles.add(vehicle)
    }
}
```

Obviously it's not automatically sorted but you can do that after adding a batch of items by running the [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method which also accepts a Comparator, but this time your comparator can focus on the specific task of detailing the ordering now that you know the list is pre-filtered so you are not concerned with trying to filter items out.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the collection and remove everything that doesn't meet your requirements using `it.remove()`.

You may also want to look at the Java 8 collections functionality that will allow you to do things like filter a collection as that will also do what you are looking for.